# Android: Get Phone Numbers in Favorites Contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I want to get all phone numbers in the favorites menu in contacts,
this is a part of my code

this code get all my contacts names and IDs

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
}
```

and this where i get my numbers

```
phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +"="+ CheckedArray.get(i), null, null); 
phones.moveToNext();
phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
String Message = DbManager.getInstance().userName+" wants to share his OneLinx profile with you";
try {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, Message, null, null);    
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}       
phones.close();
```

but in another part of my app i want to get only contacts in favorites so is there a way to do this ? can i change something here to get only favorites not all the contacts ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the parameters selection and selectionArgs of ContentProvider.query method. So you can filter those contact numbers that are "starred" (or favorites).

In the selection parameter, just add a string that containts Phone.STARRED + "=1" so the provider will give you contacts that are starred.

Comment: your solution looks promising. Could you please show a sample code snippet on how to do this?